# Why is $0/0$ ot equal to $1$?

Tags: arithmetic

If $3/3=1, 2/2=1, 1/1=1$, then why is $0/0$ undefined? Why is it not $1$?

Comment: If $1 = 0/0$, what are you going to do about $(0+0)/0$?

Comment: There can´t be a multiplicative inverse to $0$ because $0 x=0\neq1$

Comment: Division by zero is not defined in the "real number" system.  It may be defined in other number systems.  So tell us what number system you want to use...

Answer (score 1):

0/0 is not defined because you can find any couple of numbers a,b for which 0*a = 0*b . if defined, we would have 0/0 = a/b, and this for any possible values of a and b. Which makes way to many values for one same given number. ;-)